# Add single validation message for multiple fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a password reset page that looks like this

[image]

I have a validation that verifies whether the new password has been used recently.

The requirement is that if the password has been used recently, then mark both new password and confirm password fields as erroneous and display validation message as follows.

[image]

How can I add a single validation message for the two fields?

I tried this

```
ModelState.AddModelError(newpasswordfieldname, "");
ModelState.AddModelError(confirmpasswordfieldname, AccountResources.FailMinPasswordHistory);
```

but that displayed an error "The value `password` is invalid." for the new password field.

Is there any way to achieve this, other than using `TempData/ViewData`, ie, using the native form validation SDK?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you just need to compare the new password and the recent one. how about comparevalidator field? im not sure in asp.netMVC

Comment: The validation workflow works fine, the only issue i face is displaying the validation result

Comment: I see, why not use jquery? I use it to manipulate css from code behind however im not yet familiar with MVC.

Comment: you want the same message on two fields?

Comment: I want no error message in first field, just the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I found no solution using the Native MVC validation SDK, I was forced to use a dirty workaround.

In my controller

```
ModelState.AddModelError(newpasswordfieldname, "DONOTSHOW");
ModelState.AddModelError(confirmpasswordfieldname, AccountResources.FailMinPasswordAge);
```

And in my view

```
@if(ViewData.ModelState["NewPassword"]!=null && 
    ViewData.ModelState["NewPassword"].Errors.First().ErrorMessage!="DONOTSHOW")
{
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the `AddModelError(String, String)` overload?

```
ModelState.AddModelError(newpasswordfieldname, "This password was used too recently");
ModelState.AddModelError(confirmpasswordfieldname, "This password was used too recently");
```

Add the same custom message to both properties.

Comment: That will display the message twice. And FYI, I use the string overload.

Comment: Ohh, ok. In that case, probably simplest would be to add with jQuery the class 'has-error' or similar to the input field. You can either send over a bool variable to find out if you need to use it or make it depend on the error message of the confirm password prop.

Comment: Or if validation message if same as the other, set to display:none. or any of those tricks.

Comment: I thought of all those, but those don't look so neat :). If that's the only solution, I can only see this as a short fall of the MVC framework.